# Trouble using tables in settings case

Tags: python

I tried to make some settings table and read from it, but I don't really know how. I need it to be something like that.

in lua its like that as below, i need that on python

```
settings = {amount = 100}
print(settings.amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Lua, but it seems to me that, in Python terms, you want to define a class that has an attribute named `amount`, and you want an instance of that class named `settings` whose `amount` is 100.

If so, then the Python way of doing that would be:

```
class My_class():

    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount

settings = My_class(100)
```

You can verify that with `print(settings.amount)`, which gives an output of 100.

Comment: i can use it with string too?

Comment: Sure, the same code would also work, e.g., with `settings = My_class("one hundred")`

Comment: Alright, thanks! Im pretty sure i can make many from that now.